# Need help converting TSQL to PLSQL script containing variable, select top, with ties

Tags: oracle, t-sql, plsql

I have the following script, that is used to get values, which dates are closest to today.

```
DECLARE @TodayDate DATE
SET @TodayDate = Getdate()
SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES FUTURE_RETAIL_ID,
        item,
        location,
        action_date
FROM future_retail
WHERE action_date <= @TodayDate AND ROWNUM = 1;
ORDER BY row_number() over(PARTITION BY item, location ORDER BY datediff(day,action_date,@TodayDate))
```

I tried to convert it to plsql myself but cannot do that and oracle live sql doesn't help much to understand the error

```
v_today DATE;

SELECT v_today
  INTO v_today
  FROM DUAL;


SELECT WITH TIES FUTURE_RETAIL_ID,
        item,
        location,
        action_date
FROM future_retail
WHERE action_date <=v_today AND ROWNUM = 1;

ORDER BY row_number() over(PARTITION BY item, location ORDER BY (action_date - v_today))
```

I also tried

```
v_today date := sysdate;
```

tried to just use this instead of variable

```
(select CURRENT_DATE
        from dual)
```

I get multiple errors first apart from main query I get errors with variable
and when I add query it also complains about wrong FROM position.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Oracle 12C or higher version, You may use below syntax -

```
DECLARE v_today DATE;

BEGIN
     SELECT SYSDATE
       INTO v_today
       FROM DUAL;

     SELECT FUTURE_RETAIL_ID,
            item,
            location,
            action_date
       FROM future_retail
      WHERE action_date <=v_today
      ORDER BY row_number() over(PARTITION BY item, location ORDER BY (action_date - v_today))
      OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES;
END;
```

If you are using lower than 12C version, You may use below syntax -

```
DECLARE v_today DATE;

BEGIN
     SELECT SYSDATE
       INTO v_today
       FROM DUAL;

     SELECT FUTURE_RETAIL_ID,
            item,
            location,
            action_date
       FROM (SELECT FUTURE_RETAIL_ID,
                    item,
                    location,
                    action_date,
                    row_number() over(PARTITION BY item, location ORDER BY (action_date - v_today) RN
               FROM future_retail
              WHERE action_date <=v_today
              ORDER BY row_number() over(PARTITION BY item, location ORDER BY (action_date - v_today))
             )
      WHERE RN = 1;
END;
```

Comment: thanks, for some reason 1 statement crushes the system, but 2nd has some typos, trying to fix them now to see if it works

Answer (score 0):

With help of Ankit I was able to create a working script.
For some reason declaring variable crushed the whole oracle live server, but when I replaced variable with usual script to get current date it worked fine

```
SELECT FUTURE_RETAIL_ID,item,location, action_date
FROM future_retail
WHERE action_date <=(SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL)
ORDER BY row_number() over(PARTITION BY item, location ORDER BY ((SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL) - action_date))
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES;
```

Comment: You can even write only `WHERE action_date <= SYSDATE`